# Use firebase admin with REST

Tags: firebase-admin

I'm using Deno instead of node as a runtime, which makes me unable to use `firebase-admin`. I would like to implement the `listUsers` from the admin sdk in REST, but have not found any REST api references. Is there a way to use the `firebase-admin` sdk with REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Identity Toolkit APIs, the [accounts:batchGet](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/batchGet) to be specific. You'll need an access token to use those APIs since you cannot use default credentials with the REST API. Checkout the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for the same.

You can use the API explorer linked above to test APIs from the browser itself.